# Retrieving the comment count in from a Facebook comments box

Tags: php, api, facebook, comments, fbml

I use `<fb:comments>` on my website, but I can't figure out how to retrieve the comment count from a comment box with a specific XID.

I've tried intercepting all new comments with the following code:

`FB.Event.subscribe('comments.add', function(response) {
  alert("Comment was added.");
});`

I never receive the alert though. Any ideas? I just need the number of comments for any given box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking two separate questions.  1) how to get a count of comments, and 2) how to track the comment event with JavaScript.   For 2, you need the comment tag to include notify="true" in order for the event to be fired.

```
<fb:comments xid="comment_xxx" notify="true"></fb:comments>
```

Comment: Where in the world did you see a mention of the `notify="true"` attribute? It's not even mentioned in their docs!

Answer (score 4):

You can get the count of your comments with this simple fb tag:

```
<fb:comments-count href="${url_of_your_page}"></fb:comments-count> Comment
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get `comment_count` field from [`link_stat`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat) table through FQL by providing `url` of a page with your comment plugin.

If that doesn't work you can also get all comments by `xid` from `comment` table and then count them yourself (FQL doesn't support `COUNT`). But there is a limit on returned number of records, so most likely it would return only first 5,000 comments.

Comment: I also need to detect when a new comment is added so I can notify the site owner.

Answer (score 1):

I was finding the answer a lot of time, and finally i found it.

You can read comments when it is saved.

You can see: 
[Guardar comentarios facebook](http://www.blogdeprogramacion.com/2011/01/guardar-comentarios-con-api-de-facebook.html)

Answer (score 0):

**this code is working for me**

```
<script>
    // fb init 
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId:  'you app id',
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml:  true
        });

        // this event is fired where a comment is created

        FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {
            alert(response.commentID);
        });         

    };

  // im using jquery to make ajax request
  $(function(){

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=[SITE URL]",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){ 
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
          items.push(val)
          });
            alert(items[0].comments);
            console.log(items);
           }  
     });
```

**items[0].comments is what you are looking for**

> take a look in the console you can see that items is like this :

```
[Object {
id="site url",  
shares=65,  
comments=87
}]
```